# Electron-Node.js Quit app after launching external app or file

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

Is it possible to quit the main application after launching an external file or app?

```
const child = require('child_process').execFile;
const fs = require('fs');
if (fs.existsSync(updateFile)) {
   child(updateFile, function(err, data) { }); //start the update.exe
   app.quit(); //quit the app
}
```

I'm trying to open my app `updater.exe` from the `temp` directory to install the new update. I cant use the [autoUpdater](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/auto-updater) for some reason.

The `updater.exe` is created using `C#.net` and it simply replaces the old files with the new ones after download, but I can't do that while the main application is still running. I'm thinking to kill the application from the `C# .net` through [Process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process) but it doesn't feel so right for me.

Using the code above in [Electron-Node.js](https://www.electronjs.org/) the `updater.exe` also quit after calling the `app.quit()` since it's just a child of the main application. What is the alternative method?

PS: This only supports Windows. [Windows 10](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/software-download/windows10) and [11](https://www.microsoft.com/software-download/windows11) to be more specific.

Comment: Have you looked into [`child_process.spawn()`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_processspawncommand-args-options)? Maybe its `detached` option comes close to what you're trying to do...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [@AlexanderLeither](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6786876/alexander-leithner), it turns out that an option [detached](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#optionsdetached) is available in [child_process.spawn()](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_processspawncommand-args-options).

This makes it possible for the child process to continue running after the parent exits.

```
const child = require('child_process').spawn;
const subprocess = child(updateFile, {
  detached: true,  //Continue running after the parent exits.
  stdio: 'ignore'  
});  
subprocess.unref(); //To prevent the parent from waiting for a given subprocess to exit
app.quit();
```

Also, for some reason, there are four electron processes when I tried to look in Taskmanager. I had to kill it using [Process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process) in my `C# .net` to avoid IO errors when replacing files.

```
while(true) { //don't stop killing untill no more process with the same name.
    try {
        Process[] process = Process.GetProcessesByName("TestProject"); //TestProject is the name of my current project and is in the TaskManager
        if(process.Length < 1) break; //if the process doesn't exist then break this loop. 
        process[0].Kill(); //if the process exist, kill it
        process[0].WaitForExit(); //wait until the process exits
    } catch(Exception) {
        //this will throw an exception if the same process is trying to kill while it is being kill, that's okay.
    }
}
```